# Syntax error in python using quickly

Tags: python, canonical-quickly

I'm trying to create an app using quickly.  I typed in a line of code to add a font button to work.  When I did so, I "quickly ran" the app in terminal and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin/simplenotepad", line 35, in <module>
import simplenotepad
File "/home/tscholz2001/simplenotepad/simplenotepad/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from simplenotepad import SimplenotepadWindow
File "/home/tscholz2001/simplenotepad/simplenotepad/SimplenotepadWindow.py", line 29
def Gtk_font_button_get_font_name()
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You probably forgot the colon `:` after:

```
def Gtk_font_button_get_font_name()
```

It should be:

```
def Gtk_font_button_get_font_name():
```

Comment: I added the semi colon after the () and now I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/simplenotepad", line 35, in <module>
    import simplenotepad
  File "/home/tscholz2001/simplenotepad/simplenotepad/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from simplenotepad import SimplenotepadWindow
  File "/home/tscholz2001/simplenotepad/simplenotepad/SimplenotepadWindow.py", line 30
    
                                                ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: And there is no Line 30...

Comment: In python grouping of statements is determined by their indentation level. You can use either **tab** or **whitespace** for indentation but remember it should be uniform throughout the code. I would recommand to change your text editor settings and replace tabs with four **whitespaces**. Sometimes it happens that in one line you use **tab** for indentation and in another **whitespace**. Visually you can not tell the difference but interpreter will give **IndentationError**.